Bundles on stacks
We want to define what is a morphism of bundles over an algebraic stack. If $X$ is an algebraic stack and $V_n$ is the stack of rank $n$ vector bundles, a vector bundle on $X$ will be a morphism of stacks $X\to V_n$. Then, how can we define a morphism of bundles on stacks?

What is the stack of rank $n$ vector bundles?

@abx  Probably that was a rhetorical question, but one interpretation of the stack of rank $n$ vector bundles is the classifying stack $B\mathbf{GL}_n$.  Of course that interpretation gives one answer to the posted question: a $2$-morphism between the associated $1$-morphisms to the classifying stack.  However, this only gives the notion of isomorphisms of bundles on stacks.  For the "usual" notion of morphisms of bundles on stacks, one needs to interpret $B\mathbf{GL}_n$ as a $2$-truncation of a higher stack, or (better in my opinion) just work with the fppf topos of sheaves on $X$.

If you work with stacks in categories instead of stacks in groupoids, you can talk about morphisms that are not invertible. This example shows that it gives a somewhat meaningful geometric interpretation, but stacks in categories are a 2-categorical concept (in the sense of $(2,2)$-categories, or $(\infty,2)$-categories), which is a much harder thing to work with than $1$-stacks (or even $(\infty,1)$-stacks, i.e. sheaves of spaces).
